Error running `npm run dev` in Next.js project: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink
I'm encountering an error while running npm run dev in my Next.js project. Here's the error message:

$ npm run dev

constructnet@0.1.0 dev
next dev

▲ Next.js 14.1.4

Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, readlink 'C:\Users\sharon
sajan\OneDrive - Don Bosco Institute of
Technology\Desktop\ConstructNet-Next.js\constructnet.next\static\webpack\5cb4901185ad33c4.webpack.hot-update.json']
{   errno: -4071,   code: 'EINVAL',   syscall: 'readlink',   path:
'C:\Users\sharon sajan\OneDrive - Don Bosco Institute of
Technology\Desktop\ConstructNet-Next.js\constructnet\.next\static\webpack\5cb4901185ad33c4.webpack.hot-update.json'
}

.........................................
this is the error, it was working fine but all of a sudden am getting this error
cleared next.js cache, reinstalled node modules but still not working

I ran into the same thing. I had to delete the entire .next directory and that resolved the issue for myself.

Just delete the entire .next directory and run in the terminal npm run dev.
In this way you may be handle this error.
